# print obfuscated command

Tags: beamer, listings, verbatim

I want to print these two obfuscated commands in latex. I tried verbatim and listings. But, could not print the following as is.

```
cmd.exe /C"set 4i=net us&&set OyVP=er&&call set kUt=%4i%%OyVP%&&cmd /C %kUt%"

Fo^R ,,/^f , ,"  delims=lu tokens=+3 ",;%^f; ^In, ; ( ,; ' , ;a^^ss^^o^^C ; ; ^|, ; fiN^^Ds^^T^^R , n^^X ' ; ) , , ^DO , %^f;  ;w6n; ;Ssj8i/%pUblIc:~14%" ; ,(^S^e^t ^  ;  ^ ^ =^ u)& ( (^SeT ^  ^,^    =^t)  ,)&&( (^Set ^ ^ ^} ^   =n) )&&(^s^Et  ^ ^?^ ^ ^  =^s)&& (se^t ^  ^}^ ^  =e)&(  ,, ,(^S^ET  ^.^ ^  ^ =^r) ,  ;,  ; ,  )&(, , , ,, (^SEt ^ #^ ^ =^e) )&  , , ^Cal^L , ; ^Se^t  ?  =%^} ^   %%^}^ ^  %%^,^    %%;  ^ ^ %%^?^ ^ ^  %%#^ ^ %%^.^ ^  ^ %& ;; (  ; ; (ca^l^l, , E^c^ho; %? ^ %) )" ; ; |, F^OR; /^F , ,"delims=.EDkic tokens= 3 " , ,%^k , ^in, ( ,; ', ^^^^As^^^^so^^^^c; ;.psd1 ' ;) , , D^O , ;%^k -
```

I am doing this Overleaf. When encapsulating in verbatim, I get the following error.

```
Runaway argument?
cmd.exe /C"set 4i=net us&&set OyVP=er&&call set kUt=
! Paragraph ended before \@xverbatim was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.253 \end{frame}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
 slidescyberanalytics.tex, line 253
Missing $ inserted.
Check that your $'s match around math expressions. If they do, then you've probably used a symbol in normal text that needs to be in math mode. Symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ), and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x} ) must be written in math mode. See the full list here.If you intended to use mathematics mode, then use $ … $ for 'inline math mode', $$ … $$ for 'display math mode' or alternatively \begin{math} … \end{math}.

 Learn more
<inserted text> 
                $
l.253 \end{frame}

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
 slidescyberanalytics.tex, line 253
LaTeX Error: Command \end{verbatim} invalid in math mode.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.253 \end{frame}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 slidescyberanalytics.tex, line 253
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.

 Learn more
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.253 \end{frame}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 slidescyberanalytics.tex, line 253
Missing $ inserted.
Check that your $'s match around math expressions. If they do, then you've probably used a symbol in normal text that needs to be in math mode. Symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ), and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x} ) must be written in math mode. See the full list here.If you intended to use mathematics mode, then use $ … $ for 'inline math mode', $$ … $$ for 'display math mode' or alternatively \begin{math} … \end{math}.

 Learn more
<inserted text> 
                $
l.253 \end{frame}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Comment: It should work; there's not much special in those lines. What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I think the author has an issue with special characters. But is unclear in the present version.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Maybe. But this post does not contain any LaTeX document or code fragments, does it?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Certainly not. I am only trying to make suggestions to a new user. :-)

Comment: a `verbatim` will print exactly what you posted, but it will most likely be too wide to fit on a page. You need to say if it is acceptable to add linebreaks or if the long line must be kept verbatim (in which case you will need a very small font)

Comment: you have not shown the input you used but `$ l.253 \end{frame}` suggests you are using `beamer` (you had not mentioned that) in which case you may need to use `\begin{frame}[fragile]` on that frame.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle Yes, I am using Beamer in Overleaf. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: @SRIVATHSANSRINIVASAGOPALAN that is why it is _always_ best if questions include a complete small document that shows the problem, and in the case of errors you show the exact error message, don't just say it does not work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, the [fragile] option did it !! Thanks. But, as you rightly pointed out, the font-size is too small to be seen by any audience.

Comment: @SRIVATHSANSRINIVASAGOPALAN getting that to fit is your problem, not latex's you can adjust the input to have line breaks wherever you need.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat why off topic?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The original version of the question didn't look (to me) as if it was related to LaTeX and friends. But I voted to reopen now.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it didn't have a tex example document but the original question said "I want to print this verbatim in latex" which seems on topic to me (turns out it was a beamer issue, when beamer wasn't mentioned originally, but still..)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What can I say, to me it looked as if it does not belong here, but now it does.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  it's a new year, you need a new crystal ball:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good crystal balls are hard to find these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the text verbatim in latex

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\addtolength\textwidth{150pt}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-75pt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

{\fontsize{1.5pt}{2pt}\selectfont
\begin{verbatim}
cmd.exe /C"set 4i=net us&&set OyVP=er&&call set kUt=%4i%%OyVP%&&cmd /C %kUt%"

Fo^R ,,/^f , ,"  delims=lu tokens=+3 ",;%^f; ^In, ; ( ,; ' , ;a^^ss^^o^^C ; ; ^|, ; fiN^^Ds^^T^^R , n^^X ' ; ) , , ^DO , %^f;  ;w6n; ;Ssj8i/%pUblIc:~14%" ; ,(^S^e^t ^  ;  ^ ^ =^ u)& ( (^SeT ^  ^,^    =^t)  ,)&&( (^Set ^ ^ ^} ^   =n) )&&(^s^Et  ^ ^?^ ^ ^  =^s)&& (se^t ^  ^}^ ^  =e)&(  ,, ,(^S^ET  ^.^ ^  ^ =^r) ,  ;,  ; ,  )&(, , , ,, (^SEt ^ #^ ^ =^e) )&  , , ^Cal^L , ; ^Se^t  ?  =%^} ^   %%^}^ ^  %%^,^    %%;  ^ ^ %%^?^ ^ ^  %%#^ ^ %%^.^ ^  ^ %& ;; (  ; ; (ca^l^l, , E^c^ho; %? ^ %) )" ; ; |, F^OR; /^F , ,"delims=.EDkic tokens= 3 " , ,%^k , ^in, ( ,; ', ^^^^As^^^^so^^^^c; ;.psd1 ' ;) , , D^O , ;%^k -
\end{verbatim}
}
\end{document}
```

But that is an unreadably small print. Normally that wouldn't be acceptable, but as the text is anyway obfuscated perhaps that is OK here. It's in a scalable font so you can read it in PDF if you zoom in. Reading it on paper might be challenging.

Alternatively if you want a larger font you need to re-arrange the input to have shorter lines, or use a non-verbatim environment that allows line breaking, but allowing linebreaks to be automatically added to script code is somewhat dangerous as typically it will break the code.

---

---

Later edit showed that the original document was using beamer, in which case, frames using verbatim need to use

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
```

Comment: I am trying to print in Overleaf. When encapsulating the text using verbatim, I get the following error:

Comment: @SRIVATHSANSRINIVASAGOPALAN  line endings are important in tex errors, do not put it in a comment, edit your question and show a complete small document that makes the error and the exact error from the log file, in code blocks so line endings are preserved.

Comment: @SRIVATHSANSRINIVASAGOPALAN if you try the code as posted in this answer in overleaf you will get no error.